# Getting item from collection in dynamic variable

Tags: c#, dynamic, ienumerable

I'm working on some code which uses dynamic variables.

```
dynamic variable;
```

Behind scenes, this variable contains collection of Shapes which is again collection of dynamic variables.
So code like this working fine:

```
foreach(var shape in variable.Shapes) //Shapes is dynamic type too
{
    double height = shape.Height; 
}
```

I need to get first item height from this collection.
This hack works well:

```
double height = 0;
foreach(var shape in variable.Shapes)
{
    height = shape.Height; //shape is dynamic type too
    break;
}
```

Is there better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8):

#### Description

You can  use the  `LINQ` method `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`to get the first item.

> **First()** - Returns the first element of a sequence.
>
> **FirstOrDefault()** - Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements.

#### Sample

```
using System.Linq;

double height = 0;

// this will throw a exception if your list is empty
var item = System.Linq.Enumerable.First(variable.Shapes);
height = item.Height;

// in case your list is empty, the item is null and no exception will be thrown
var item = System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(variable.Shapes);
if (item != null)
{
     height = item.Height;
}
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - LINQ (Language-Integrated Query)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)
- [MSDN - Enumerable.First Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx)
- [MSDN - Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

Because `variable` is `dynamic`, you won't be able to evaluate `variable.Shapes.First()`, since determination of extension methods occurs at compile time, and dynamic invocation occurs at runtime. You will have to call the static method explicitly,

`System.Linq.Enumerable.First<TType>(variable.Shapes).Height`.
Where `TType` is the expected type of the items in the enumerable.

Otherwise, use LINQ as others have suggested.

Comment: You're right, extension methods aren't supported by dynamic typing in the form of extension methods! +1

Comment: Makes sense too. How could LINQ possibly know what the dynamic object is when it isn't evaluated till runtime

Comment: Actually, no, it doesn't work, exception:
{Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.First<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.